# Undefined signal in simulation

Tags: vhdl, system-verilog, system-verilog-assertions, synopsys-vcs

I am trying to verify a design written in VHDL using SystemVerilog's assertions. however I got a problem when I have a non defined signal'X'

Just for example here is a code of a Comparator:

```
entity FP_comparator_V2 is
port (
    comp_in1                    : in    std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    comp_in2                    : in    std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    less                        : out   std_logic;
    equal                       : out   std_logic;
    greater                     : out   std_logic
    );
end FP_comparator_V2;

architecture behav of FP_comparator_V2 is
   -- signal, component etc. declarations

begin
   -- architecture body

    process(comp_in1, comp_in2)
    begin
    if comp_in1 = comp_in2 then
        equal                   <= '1';
        less                    <= '0';
        greater                 <= '0';

    else 
        equal                   <= '0';
...



   end if;
    end process;        
end behav;
```

and the assertions

```
property FP_Comparator_V2_1_1;
@(posedge `assertion_check_clk29M4912 or negedge `assertion_check_clk29M4912)
    (fp_comp_intf.Comp_in1 === fp_comp_intf.Comp_in2) |-> (fp_comp_intf.equal);

endproperty

DS_3_4_69_1_1:
assert property(FP_Comparator_V2_1_1);
cover property(FP_Comparator_V2_1_1);

property FP_Comparator_V2_1_2;
    @(posedge `assertion_check_clk29M4912 or negedge `assertion_check_clk29M4912)
        (fp_comp_intf.Comp_in1 !== fp_comp_intf.Comp_in2) |-> (!fp_comp_intf.equal);
endproperty

DS_3_4_69_1_2:
assert property(FP_Comparator_V2_1_2);
cover property(FP_Comparator_V2_1_2);
```

When Comp_int1 and Comp_int2 have defined values the simulation works fine if one of them have a undefined value also works fine but when both signals have undefined value it gives error For example :

> Comp_int1= 48xx_xxxx; Comp_int2=47xx_xxxx ==>Equal = 1

I suppose it compares bit by bit so Equal should be '0' Please if you know a book or a website explaining the behavior of signals after synthesis or the logic behind undefined signals I would be thankful if you put it in a comment

thank you

Comment: You need to have signal values from both sides of the world at least. There are IEEE publications and white papers which describe verilog/vhdl interoperability,  regarding signal value mapping, timing and synchronization. i.e. https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/6e5e/b063493d6c90b38b73ff71003bfadb453777.pdf.  Might want to talk to synopsys directly.

Comment: Please could you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest eliminating undefined values for signals in the design first. You can do this by initializing values to those signals in all possible cases. This helps in eliminating the X-propagation in the design.